# Implementing of server in C winapi

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, client-server, interlocked

i'm new to multi-threads and want to design server

this is my current code :

```
typedef struct Session
{
    HANDLE handlers[2];
    //HANDLE h_Send;
    //main session handler
    HANDLE h_MainHandler;
    HANDLE sema_MessageQ;

    char* UserName;
    SOCKET Socket;

    PList MessageQ;

}Session,*pSession; 
#define NUM_OF_WORKER_THREADS 5

#define MAX_LOOPS 5

#define SEND_STR_SIZE 256
static Session ClientSessions[NUM_OF_WORKER_THREADS];

void MainServer()
{
    int Ind;
    int Loop;
    int bindRes;
    int ListenRes;
    unsigned long Address;
    char SendStr[SEND_STR_SIZE];

    SOCKET MainSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    SOCKADDR_IN service;

    XPacket Packet;
    TransferResult_t RecvRes;
    TransferResult_t SendRes;

    //doing all the WSAStartup / bind / listen 
    //and error checkinh


    // Initialize all thread handles to NULL, to mark that they have not been initialized
    for ( Ind = 0; Ind < NUM_OF_WORKER_THREADS; Ind++ )
        ClientSessions[Ind].h_MainHandler = NULL;

    printf( "Waiting for a client to connect...\n" );

    for ( Loop = 0; Loop < MAX_LOOPS; Loop++ )
    {
        SOCKET AcceptSocket = accept( MainSocket, NULL, NULL );
        if ( AcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
        {
            printf( "Accepting connection with client failed, error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError()); 
            goto server_cleanup_3;
        }

        printf( "Client Connected.\n" );

        Ind = FindFirstUnusedThreadSlot();

        if ( Ind == NUM_OF_WORKER_THREADS ) //no slot is available
        { 
            printf( "No slots available for client, dropping the connection.\n" );
            closesocket( AcceptSocket ); //Closing the socket, dropping the connection.
            continue;
        } 
        else    
        {
            /*check that user name is not in use*/
            char *AcceptedStr = NULL;
            //get UserName
            RecvRes = ReceivePacket(&Packet, AcceptSocket);

            if ( RecvRes == TRNS_FAILED || RecvRes == TRNS_DISCONNECTED )
            {
                printf( "Service socket error while reading, closing socket.\n" );
                closesocket( AcceptSocket );
                continue;
            }
            if (FALSE == CheckForUsedName((char*)Packet.Data))
            {
                strcpy(SendStr ,(char*)Packet.Data);
                strcpy( SendStr + strlen((char*)Packet.Data), " already taken!" );
                SendRes = (TransferResult_t)PROTOCOL_SendCommand(
                        SendStr,
                        strlen(SendStr) + 1,
                        PROT_SERVER_RECEIVE_SYSTEM_MSG,
                        AcceptSocket);
                closesocket(AcceptSocket);
                continue;
            }

            printf("\r\nCode:%d Length:%lu Text:%s",Packet.Code,Packet.Length,(char*)Packet.Data);

            ClientSessions[Ind].UserName = (char*)Packet.Data;
            ClientSessions[Ind].Socket = AcceptSocket;


            ClientSessions[Ind].h_MainHandler = CreateThread(
                NULL,
                0,
                ( LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE ) ServiceThread,
                &( ClientSessions[Ind]),
                0,
                NULL
            );
        }
    } // for ( Loop = 0; Loop < MAX_LOOPS; Loop++ )

//~~~~~~~~server clean up~~~~~~~~~~~ 
server_cleanup_3:
    CleanupWorkerThreads();

server_cleanup_2:
    if ( closesocket( MainSocket ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
        printf("Failed to close MainSocket, error %ld. Ending program\n", WSAGetLastError() ); 

server_cleanup_1:
    if ( WSACleanup() == SOCKET_ERROR )     
        printf("Failed to close Winsocket, error %ld. Ending program.\n", WSAGetLastError() );
}
```

my current code is waiting for number of client to connect before waiting for the clients to disconnect
this is obviously not very good
what I want is something of form

server:

```
{
    //accept first client
    \\while( InterlockedAdd(&number_of_connected_client , 0) >0 ) ?
    while(number_of_connected_client > 0)        
    {
      //wait for new client
    }

    //close server
}
```

each client session :

```
{

    //do somthing
    //once finish
    InterlockedDecrement(number_of_connected_client );

}
```

**my question** is how to implement the `while()` part not in `spin-lock`

Comment: In my opinion you should not be using lock free methods here. You'll only end up with a race. Use a lock. Protect the connection and disconnection of clients by that lock. When the client count goes to zero, signal termination. Perhaps by signaling an event that the main thread blocks on. When the main thread detects that the event is signaled, it shuts down.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure i understand , can you please publish some code or maybe link to more complete example

Comment: I don't have time. Do you know what an event is in multi-threading?

Answer (score 0):

The server design I have used before is very similar to what you already have.

A main server thread is waiting for connections from clients (just change your for loop to make it an infinite loop (e.g. while(1) { //accept connection etc. }). When the main thread accepts a connection, it passes the socket (returned by accept) to a worker thread.

The Tricky part of this design is managing the worker threads, somehow choosing a worker thread for each client connection, and passing the socket to the chosen worker thread.

I notice that you create a new worker thread for each connection. This has the advantage of being simple, the disadvantage of course is the performance hit of creating a thread for each connection.

I created a server many years ago (when I didn't know any better), and the solution I came up with used the Windows [Synchronization Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360(v=vs.85).aspx#event_functions). I used Windows Events to coordinate between the main thread and the worker threads. I won't go into details because I would never do it that way again. It was too complex. I was basically doing everything manually.

If I had to do this today, I would just use the Windows Thread Pool (see the [QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684957(v=vs.85).aspx) function).